# Extract specific rows from file_B, where the row is specified by numbers in file_A

Tags: awk, grep

I want to extract specific rows from file_B, where the row is specified by the number in file_A.

I know there are a lot of answers to similar questions, but most have to do with strings rather than integers.

File_A

```
1
3
5
7
11
```

FIle_B

```
MT 50000
groupI 50000
groupI 150000
groupI 250000
groupII 350000
groupII 450000
groupIII 550000
groupIII 650000
groupIII 750000
groupIV 850000
groupIV 950000
```

File_output

```
MT 50000
groupI 150000
groupII 350000
groupIII 550000
groupIV 950000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$0];next}(FNR in a)' File_A File_B
```